# What does the default allocator do when a std::vector is resized (via either reserve() or resize())?

Tags: c++, stl

What does the default allocator do when a std::vector is resized (via either reserve() or resize())?

- The memory chunk internally used by the `std::vector` is actually resized.
- A new memory chunk is allocated, data is moved (e.g., `std::move`d) from the old memory chunk to the new one, and finally the old memory chunk is deallocated.

Comment: I am not so sure that realloc would be efficient. One of the advantages of the `std::allocator` is that it can make some assumptions on the way memory is obtained, and thus tailor the actual allocated chunk to fit *exactly* a memory block. Many allocators have moved away from multi-size mixing and toward arenas of fixed-size block: in this new philosophy, you don't want to extend a block in its arena, it breaks the arena invariant, so you need to move toward a new arena. If `vector` is clever, it can *know* the size of the blocks in advance, and adjust the capacity accordingly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C++ allocators do not support anything like C's `realloc`.  Whenever `vector` needs more memory, it has to allocate new storage, move from old to new, and deallocate the old.

Either way, `realloc` wouldn't suit `vector`.  With typical allocators, `realloc` will only save you a heavy copy operation if you are shrinking its size, or in some cases growing by only a few bytes. `vector` doesn't ever shrink, and it only grows in very large steps.

Note that move support is a new behavior in C++ 2011. Previous versions will copy.

Comment: Could vector not be specialized to use realloc for POD types with default allocator?

Comment: It definitely could, though I'm not aware of any implementations which do.

Comment: @Pubby That would break with the container requirements in general, and cannot be applied unless the type is POD **and** the allocator is the default allocator. If you also consider that in many cases realloc cannot extend the region and needs to allocate copy and free the memory, it is probably not worth the pain in general.

Comment: Personally I wouldn't put any effort into trying to resize the used memory buffer: the chances that the buffer could be increased are rather low. I don't have any statistics for `realloc()` but I would guess that normally it won't be able to resize the allocate memory buffer, i.e. `realloc()` is effectively a shortcut for `malloc()`, `memmove()`, and `free()`.

Answer (score 2):

When a vector needs to grow, in any operation including resize/reserve, but also push_back, insert... A new memory block is obtained, and the elements in the old dynamic array are either copied or *moved* to the new location (if the type supports *moving*). After this is completed, the old elements are destroyed and the old memory released.

Note that *move* has a specific meaning in the standard that differs from the intuitive meaning: management of the *contents* of the objects (rather than the objects) are passed from the original object to the new.

Comment: That definition of *move* seems intuitive to me.

Comment: @EduardoLeón the object does not *move*, in most cases the contents don't *move* either, only responsibility is transferred.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the other answers which explain the semantics, an important difference to consider between `reserve` and `resize` is that `reserve` just allocates the memory without initializing it while `resize` allocates memory and default initializes it.